# Create lambda roles and policy before lambda exists

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Hello I am creating two repos. one that creates the role and policy for a lambda function and the other one creates the actual lambda. I have a problem in my role/policy repo, how do I define or set the lambda arn if the lambda is not created yet (created by the second repo). Any suggestions on how to accomplish it.

```
{
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                {"Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaFunction", "Arn"] }
                            ]
                        }
```

```
       "LambdaPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
            "Properties": {
              "Roles": [ { "Ref": "LambdaRole" } ],
                "PolicyName": { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "LambdaPolicy", { "Ref": "CISuffix" } ]] },
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                            "Resource": [
                              { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:logs:", {"Ref" :  "AWS::Region"}, ":", {"Ref": "AccountNumber"},":*" ]] }
                             ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                                "logs:PutLogEvents"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:logs:", {"Ref" :  "AWS::Region"}, ":", {"Ref": "AccountNumber"},":log-group:/aws/lambda/*" ]] }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                {"Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaFunction", "Arn"] }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Action": [
                                "kms:Decrypt"
                             ],
                            "Resource": { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:logs:", {"Ref" :  "AWS::Region"}, ":", {"Ref": "AccountNumber"},":log-group:/aws/lambda/Lambda:*" ]] },
                            "Effect": "Allow"
                        },
                        {
                            "Action": [
                                "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
                                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                                "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
                            ],
                            "Resource": { "Fn::Join": [ "", ["arn:aws:secretsmanager:", {"Ref" :  "AWS::Region"}, ":", {"Ref": "AccountNumber"}, ":secret:MySecretsABC" ]] },
                            "Effect": "Allow"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to create the lambda function and then you can attach the tole to it. It cannot be done other way around.